# parent package in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to execute 29 ssis packages. So planning to create one master package which will execute all these packages. I don't know how to implement this. Can you please explain in brief. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article does a pretty good job on giving a high level summary of what a master package does, which is basically a package executing other packages in the control flow: http://dichotic.wordpress.com/2006/10/30/creating-the-master-package/

This article goes over logging, variable scope, transactions, etc. from a fairly high level : http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:zMWg5KkFGZcJ:dmachicago.com/WhitePapers/SSIS%2520Master%2520Control%2520Package.doc+ssis+master+package+template&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly, just use the execute package task. You have to deploy your ssis packages to the server first for this to work.